# What may be causing this error: Error in xx[[1]] : subscript out of bounds

Tags: r

I had a dataframe and am trying to use the survey package in R on it. I also have a simplified, testing dataframe here that ends up returning the same error:

```
library(survey)

df <- data.frame(
  pid = 1:10,
  sex = rep(c('Men', 'Women'), each = 5),
  stratum = rep(1, 10),
  psu = c('101007', '201139', '202002', '101007', '201139', '202002', '101007', '201139', '202002', '101007'),
  wstep1 = c(2644.070, 5990.753, 2909.657, 2909.657, 3305.544, 6980.915, 2909.657, 4719.190, 2909.657, 3393.434)
)

test_weigh <- svydesign(ids = ~psu,         # 1 for no cluster ids
                        weights = ~wstep1,  # weight variable created above
                        strata = ~stratum,  # sampling was stratified by district
                        data = df           # have to specify the dataset
)

# Calculate the total count of individuals
total_individuals_alg <- svytotal(~1,
                                  design = test_weigh,
                                  na.rm = TRUE)
```

This code returns `Error in xx[[1]] : subscript out of bounds`

I've tried multiple methods but kept running into the same error/some other kind of error. I would expect to get the total weighted counts of individuals if not for the error, but am not sure how to resolve it. My question was closed previously because I did not provide enough information to help others reproduce the problem/understand what went wrong, so let me know if I need to provide anything else!

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, in `survey`, there is no straightforward way to calculate the total count of individuals.

I suggest you try this instead:

```
library(surveytable)
set_survey(test_weigh)
set_count_int()
options(surveytable.check_present = FALSE)
total()
```

```
                                Survey info {test_weigh}                                 
┌───────────┬──────────────┬────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Variables │ Observations │ Design                                                     │
├───────────┼──────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│         5 │           10 │ Stratified 1 - level Cluster Sampling design (with         │
│           │              │ replacement)                                               │
│           │              │ With (3) clusters.                                         │
│           │              │ svydesign(ids = ~psu, weights = ~wstep1, strata =          │
│           │              │ ~stratum, data = df)                                       │
└───────────┴──────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

         Total {test_weigh}         
┌────────┬───────┬────────┬────────┐
│ Number │    SE │     LL │     UL │
├────────┼───────┼────────┼────────┤
│ 38,673 │ 1,874 │ 34,565 │ 43,269 │
└────────┴───────┴────────┴────────┘
```

The way to do this with just `survey` is:

```
test_weigh$variables$Total = 1
svytotal(~ Total, test_weigh)
```

```
      total     SE
Total 38672 1874.4
```